# Gradle - use dependency as other project from artifactory

Tags: java, maven, gradle, artifactory

I have 2 gradle projects. A and B. A depends on B. Also I uploaded B as a set of artifacts to the artifactory local server. I used maven publish. Then I try to use B as dependency in A. I`m trying to use it as maven dependency, so I wrote

```
repositories {
    //  mavenCentral();

    maven {
        url "http://localhost:8081/artifactory/myprjb-common/"
        artifactUrls "http://localhost:8081/artifactory/myprjb-common/"
        credentials {
            username = "admin"
            password = "password"
        }
    }
    jcenter();
}
```

But, it always try to download jars from repo1. I think I misunderstood something. First of all I don't quite understand why do I need maven, also I don't understand is my artifacts publication equals to maven install. And how to use B as dependency for A? So how I see it: work on B, publish, work on A, pull dependencies from B

Comment: what is "repo1" where it tries to download from?

Comment: Repo1.maven.org thanks

Comment: Why does your development process depend on project B being available in that (local) maven repo?

Comment: I just don't know how to do it better. Project B is expected to reside in artifactory, while project A will be installed on many different servers. That`s why I decided to create 2 separate projects but not sure how to debug them

Comment: It's unlikely Gradle tries to download from maven central. It's not in the list of the repositories. I think it will be better if you share the log.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thank you for your answers, but I fixed it by placing repositories into allprojects closure, and this is not clear, because repositories are supposed to be global setting, but anyway, I placed it inside allprojects closure.